# object tag box model (width & padding) in Firefox 6

Tags: firefox, object, padding, css

Hello I'm wondering why does my Firefox keep applying a wrong (?) box model to my video embeds? It doesn't happen on Chrome.
The same CSS rules should apply, but if the object tag has *data="whatever"* and/or *type="application/x-shockwave-flash"*, its width would then include padding without extending.

check http://3dolab.net/test/ffobject.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you point to a testcase showing this behavior, please?

Comment: You need to include a) relevant source code and/or output, or b) link to a fiddle/live display of the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Just added the link. Look at the structure: the youtube embedded video doesn't have a "type" attribute in the "object" tag

Answer (score 0):

Even `box-sizing` don't help (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing).

It's firefox's bug.

Solution: you can only use wrapper div with padding.

`<div class="video">video here</div>`

`div.video{display:inline-block;padding:0 20px;}`